# R Date format with months and days of two digits

Tags: r

I needed to turn character Date "2008-1-1" to numeric 20080101, but what I get is 200811, could anybody help me with this? Thank you very much. This is my code:

```
year <- c(2008:2012)
mth <- c(1:5)  
day <- c(1:5) 
A <- data.frame(cbind(year,mth,day)) 
date.ch <- as.character(with(A, paste(year, mth, day, sep="-")))
date.n <- as.numeric(with(A, paste(year, mth, day, sep="")))
```

Comment: You may have to use `sprintf` to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `as.numeric(format(as.Date(date.ch), '%Y%m%d'))`

```
[1] 20080101 20090202 20100303 20110404 20120505
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Andrie mentioned, `sprintf` is a nice function:

```
with(A, as.numeric(sprintf("%i%02i%02i", year, mth, day)))
# [1] 20080101 20090202 20100303 20110404 20120505
```

As @mplourde noted in a comment that has since disappeared into the ether, if you only have the `date.ch` object, you could

```
as.numeric(strftime(date.ch, format = "%Y%m%d"))
```

Comment: @mplourde, ah, yes. I knew there were two reasons I up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about simple multiplication and addition?

```
A <- data.frame(cbind(year=rep(2008:2011,6),mth=rep(1:12,2),day=1:24))
with(A, year*1e4 + mth*1e2 + day)
```